# Error Code: 1098. Can't generate a unique log-filename /data/mysql-binlog/relay-bin.(1-999)

Tags: mysql, replication

After starting MySQL 5.5 I receive the error message:

```
Error Code: 1098. Can't generate a unique log-filename /data/mysql-binlog/relay-bin.(1-999)
```

Can anyone point me out what the problem is? The error pops up when I try to call `CHANGE MASTER TO ...`, the machine is set up to work as a production slave.

As you can see I have changed the replay-bin directory to another location due to disk space, but I am not sure if it relates to the problem.

Comment: Have you checked to see what's in that directory? Is it stuffed with files?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, no it is empty now, although the first time I received the error I went to check and there were 2 (supposedly old) relay and binlog index files, which I deleted then. The error has not changed after deleting them, though.

Comment: Any luck fixing it? What did you find out?

Comment: No, in the end I just gave up on setting another directory for the relay-bin files and used the default settings.